# How do I import certain parts of a module with require?

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, ecmascript-6, require

I am trying to figure out how I would write the equivalent of:

```
import { AppRegistry, Image } from 'react-native';
```

Using `require` instead of `import`, such as:

```
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
```

How can I achieve the same functionality with `require`?

Answer (score 4):

Use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const { AppRegistry, Image } = require('react-native');
```

Since `require` returns a module object that contains all the exports of the module (`react-native`) as properties (try logging `require('react-native')`), you can select which properties to give explicit bindings to with destructuring assignment, thus it's functionally equivalent to the ES2015 module syntax:

```
import { AppRegistry, Image } from 'react-native';
```